# ng-model not updating value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-change

I have a drop down that is supposed to change a slider (angular-slick).  The select menu is displaying the choices, and when a selection is made the slides are not updating.  I'm using angular 1.3.0.

I believe I have narrowed this down to the model not updating the value.

Here is my html:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="d.id as d.category for d in draggableObjects | object2Array | orderBy:'id'" ng-change="updateSlide()" ng-model="selectedSlideId"></select>

            <slick class="slider" objs="obj" data="draggableObjects" settings="slickConfig" ng-if="slideLoaded">
                <li ng-repeat="obj in draggableObject.item" class="draggable-item slide">
                    <div ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="obj" data-allow-transform="true">
                        <img ng-src="{{obj.src}}" alt="{{obj.name}}">
                        {{obj.name}}
                    </div>
                </li>
            </slick>
```

Here is the init and function that is supposed to update to the model to trigger ng-change:

```
// selection from the select dropdown
        $scope.$watch('selectedSlideId', function(newVal, oldVal) {
            if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                $scope.draggableObject = $scope.draggableObjects[newVal];
                console.log('finally!');
            } else {
                $scope.draggableObject = $scope.draggableObjects[1];
                console.log('id not updated');
            }
        });
        // init dashboard
        $scope.selectedSlideId = '1';
```

And here is the json object that is being sorted thru:

```
// draggable objects
    $scope.draggableObjects = {
        1: {
            id: '1',
            category: 'Slider',
            item: [
                {name:'slider one', src: 'images/placeholderslider.png'},
                {name:'slider two', src: 'images/placeholderslider2.png'},
                {name:'slider three', src: 'images/placeholderslider3.png'},
                {name:'slider four', src: 'images/placeholderslider4.png'},
                {name:'slider five', src: 'images/placeholderslider5.png'}
            ]
        },
        2: {
            id: '2',
            category: 'News',
            item: [
                {name:'news one', src: 'images/placeholdernews.png'},
                {name:'news two', src: 'images/placeholdernews2.png'},
                {name:'news three', src: 'images/placeholdernews3.png'},
                {name:'news four', src: 'images/placeholdernews4.png'},
                {name:'news five', src: 'images/placeholdernews5.png'}
            ]
        }
    };
```

Angular slick appears to be updating using ng-if and a timeout:

```
// init and reInit slick
    $scope.slideLoaded = true;
    $scope.updateSlide = function() {
        $scope.slideLoaded = false;
        console.log('slide update');
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.slideLoaded = true;
        });
    };
```

In the console I'm getting "id not updated" (from the selection init), and "slide update" when a selection is made from the dropdown, when I should also be seeing "finally!" from the model changing the selected value.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I also used to have this problem while using `$scope.$watch('modelname' ,..`. I currently use this function as -

```
$scope.$watch(
   function(){ return $scope.modelname;}, function(newVal, oldVal){
   ....... 
   }
)
```

writing a `function` to return `model` in place of `modelname` (string).This never fails.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I reworked the script and unfortunately, I'm still not seeing my slides update with the console printing "id not updated."  I removed my filters (thinking I may be returning the wrong value type), but still not seeing "finally!" printing to the console.  It seems like newVal, and oldVal are not getting compared.

Comment: Ok I caught the wrong, which happened to me. If there was a problem in comparison and  `oldVal` ,`newVal` are string then you should compare with `str1.equals(str2)` method not with `==`.

Comment: Is there a way you could post the updated code?  I'd really appreciate it.